# Modify data before render

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

What is the proper way to change data before rendering a template in below example?

`model()` from my route:

```
  model({contractId}){
    const cities = this.store.query('city', {contractId});
    return Ember.RSVP.hash({ cities});
  }
```

Then in my template:

```
{{orders/order-form cities=model.cities}}
```

And finally, in my component I'd like to change something in cities, so I created computed object in this way:

```
 cityOptions: Ember.computed('cities', function(){
    return this.get('cities').map((data)=> ({key: data.id, value: data.name}));
  }),
```

But `this.get('cities')` is returning something like this: `Class {modelName: "city", query: Object, store: Class, manager: RecordArrayManager…}` instead of data. Does anyone know something cool way to get pure data from `this.get('cities')`? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Always use `get` method to get the property. if you want to convert `DS.RecordArray` to normal array then you can use `toArray`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

const {get} = Ember;

export default Ember.Component.extend({

  cityOptions: Ember.computed('cities.@each.name', 'cities.@each.id', function(){
    return this.get('cities').map((city) => ({
      key: get(city, 'id'),
      value: get(city, 'name'),
    }));
  }),
});
```

The important thing here is, that `cities` is an ember array of ember data objects. They are not normal plain JS objects, so you have to use `Ember.get(obj, 'prop')` or `obj.get('prop')` instead of `obj.prop`!

Answer (score -1):

you could always use toJSON() like so...
`this.get('cities').toJSON()`
cities is an array of DS.model, if you want a POJO, you need to convert it.

```
cityOptions: Ember.computed('cities', function(){ return 
  this.get('cities').map((aModel)=> ( 
     return aModel.toJSON().map((data)=> (
         return {key: data.id, value: data.name})) 
     )); 
}),
```

Comment: I can't do that within Ember.Component

Comment: OK I thought you were in a controller since you mentioned the route and the template.. but I think it doesn't matter
you can pass your model to your component and then do the conversion.
`
 cityOptions: Ember.computed('cities', function(){
    return this.get('cities').map((aModel)=> (
        return aModel.toJSON().map((data)=> ({key: data.id, value: data.name}))
  ));
  }),
`

Comment: it works for me:   `cityOptions: Ember.computed('cities', function(){
    return this.get('cities').map(el=>({key: el.id, value: el.data.name}));
  }),`, but i thought, it exist something better.

Comment: `toJSON` is highly unnecessary here! It will run the entire serializer, not the best idea if you just want two properties!